# How do I use regexes properly in the matches() function (java)?

Tags: java, regex, overlapping-matches

I am trying to make a registration form in Java that accepts a string in the form of: ok@ok.ok, right now, I have -

```
(email.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

which I need it to also accept `@, _,-,.` symbols but am unsure how to add it into the regex shown earlier.

As well as this I am aware that there is a way to separate to accept an amount of characters, and then read a specific symbol, (in my case it would be "@" and "." for the email) but am unable to implement it, something along the lines of

```
(email.matches("[^a-zA-Z0-9]{1-99}[1][@][^a-zA-Z0-9]{1-99}[1][.][^a-zA-Z0-9]+")
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
[^@]+@[^.]+\\..+
```

Explanation:

```
[^@]+ - match everything up until the @ character
@     - match the @ character
[^.]+ - match everything up until the . character
\\.   - match the . character
.+    - match the rest
```

In case you would like to access the different parts of the email address, i.e., what was provided before and after the @ sign, you can additionally wrap those parts of the expression in parenthesis (search for "groups" in the context of regular expressions to learn more about that).